# can we wait with ngStyle angular5

Tags: angular, styles

I, i try change ngStyle with a wait 3 secondes, this is my snippet:

```html
 public alertStyles=0;
  onSelectMenu(menu) {
console.log(menu.catego, "****");

setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("wait ***");
  this.alertStyles = { 
    'display': 'none',
  }
  
}, 3000);
```

when I click on the another menu i would like this menu si hidde for wait 3 seconde this is my view:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="cacheMenu" >
  un test
  <ul id="menuHorizon" class="showMenuFixed">
    <li class="item" *ngFor="let menu of categories,let i = index" (click)="selectMenuEvent($event)" role="navigation">
      <a (click)="onSelectMenu(menu)">{{menu.catego}}</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menuContact" class="item">
      <a (click)="bascule()"> Contactez-moi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="titrePage">
  <div >
    <h1>{{titrePage}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

the is not hide menu, but i have console log show wait *** after 3 seconde.
I with ngStyle we can do it ? or we muste use another solution ?
thank for reply

Answer (score 1):

You must use an arrow function in the `setTimeout` callback. Otherwise `this` will not refer to your component class.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div [ngStyle]="style">Hello</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  style = { color: 'red' };

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.style = { color: 'blue' }, 3000);

    // this will not work
    // setTimeout(function () {
    //   this.style = { color: 'blue' };
    // }, 3000);

  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aysirw)

Comment: thanks , if i whan return color red ?  i simply function() { this.style = {color:'red'}} is sufficient when i would create bottom return color red ?

Comment: if you want to return the color only, the binding would look like `[style.color]="style"`

Comment: This is more a more code efficient way of doing what you are trying to do. Use this answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable by using a *ngIf template.

Bind a boolean variable in typescript and show the none styled div when the boolean is false, and the styled div when it's true.

Bind the boolean typescript variable to a setTimeout callback

```
setTimeout(() => ..some code, 3000)
```

3000 = 3s

You can put this in your ngOnInit, if you want to start the timer upon initialization.